# raku REPL appears unresponsive on `cygwin` under WIndows 8

Tags: printing, raku

I have `cygwin` under Windows 8 and I've installed and run `raku` which I understand to be just Perl6.
I wanted to print some strings and numbers but `say` doesn't do the job (please see the black snippet below) it just do nothing unlike it is described here:

[image]

[image]

```
hynek0@hynek /cygdrive/c/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU
$ raku --version
This is Rakudo version 2020.05.1 built on MoarVM version 2020.05
implementing Raku 6.d.
```

**EDIT 2**

[image]

**EDIT 3**
[image]

Comment: This looks very strange.  What does `raku --version` say?

Comment: If you look closely at the text you're following it shows `> say "Hello, World"` and *not* `say "Hello, World"`. That initial `> ` corresponds to the REPL prompt, analogous to your system `$` prompt. It's not appearing. My guess is that the `raku` you've installed is just accepting lines of input, waiting for you to finish entering a bunch of lines. If so, pressing Control-D will presumably end  the input and your code will run. If you'll confirm (or reject) my guess we can try to figure out what's going on, which is presumably something to do with `cygwin` or the `raku` that you've installed.

Comment: Do you need to install `Readline` or `Linenoise` to get the REPL working properly?

Comment: @jubilatious1 theoretically that should be only to have better editing capabilities on the REPL, it shouldn't be needed for making it work.

Comment: On Windows 10, it works for me out of the box on Cygwin. I downloaded the binary distribution of Raku 2021.05, and did not have to install `Readline` or `Linenoise` modules..

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen See my EDIT at the very bottom for Raku version.

Comment: @raiph Control-D doesn't work either :-(

Comment: @HåkonHægland I cannot install `Raku 2021.05` it provides `tar.gz` files only and **not** `.msi`. Could you please give me a link to `msi` type file of `Raku 2021.05` ?

Comment: @raiph How do I run `raku` to obtain `>` ?

Comment: @user2925716  *"it provides tar.gz files only and not .msi"* : I don't think you need .msi, just unpack the `.tar.gz` and move the resulting folder to e.g. `C:\rakudo`. It contains a precompiled binary at `bin\raku.exe`. So I just made sure that my `PATH` environment variable contains `C:\rakudo\bin` and if you are going to use `zef` also include `C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\bin` in `PATH`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland A very strange things happens. When I copy `raku.exe` to a new file it works. But after executing it stops working. I just need to copy it another time. When you would direct me at `raku 2021` msi things would be much easier!

Comment: @HåkonHægland I cannot google it up by myself.

Comment: @jjmerelo Thanks for the note! The only issue I see then is whether or not the terminal has entered the Raku REPL. I've actually seen a similar situation where running `raku script_name.p6` at a bash prompt drops the terminal into a similar `stdin` 'accept input linewise' mode (in the absence of any `prompt` commands). For other interpreters/REPLs I've always understood that an explicit `-` dash is required on the shell command line, but apparently not in Raku. Anyway I hope someone with expert-level  `bash`-, `fish`-, `zsh`-, etc. experience may provide direction here.

Comment: @jubilatious1 Please see my **EDIT 2** `-` hasn't helped. Also please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67753788/prompt-not-appearing-after-running-perl).

Comment: See https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4378 - probably same issue.

Comment: What does `raku -e 'say $*IN.t'` say?

Comment: Does a REPL start if you run `raku --repl-mode=interactive` ?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Irregularly, see my 3rd **EDIT**.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen It says `False`.

Comment: Then `$*IN.t` returning `False` is probably the underlying issue why the REPL isn't started.  Raku thinks there's nobody behind the keyboard, so it assumes you're going to pipe the program to be executed.

Comment: @user2925716 You've hit a bug, something to do with `raku` on your system, likely due to your version of `cygwin` or of Windows . (@HåkonHægland reports it's not just `raku`: "On Win10, it works for me out of the box on Cygwin.") Please click link in .@Coke's comment above / Liz's answer below and add comment there: "Looks like I have same problem -- running `raku` inside `cygwin` on Windows 8 hangs - REPL never appears", output of `raku --version` (i.e. same as in your answer, but as text), version info for your version of `cygwin` and of Windows 8, and your answer to `$*IN.t` question. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably the same bug as reported with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4378 .  It looks like Raku thinks there's nobody behind the keyboard (`$*IN.t` returning `False`) and thus switches to slurping the program to execute from STDIN.

At this point, I can only see a workaround: execute you example code with `raku -e`.

Comment: The issue to which you linked is about the "git bash" environment, which is MSYS (or MSYS2?) This is a unix-emulation environment very similar to Cygwin. It's not surprising the issue affects both.

Comment: @ikegami Right, but why do I need to press `enter` twice do get the result of `1+1` or even `1` when executed with `raku --repl-mode=interactive` ?

Comment: Probably related.