# prompt not appearing after running `perl`

Tags: perl, cygwin, software-distribution

I have asked a similar question [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744623/raku-repl-appears-unresponsive-on-cygwin-under-windows-8) but it eventually evolved into a series of comments. So once again, what package should I install to see the following prompt `>` after running `perl` but now **not** `raku` (all under `Cygwin`)?

[image]

**EDIT**
`-l` doesn't work either.

[image]

**EDIT 2**
`Perl -d -e1` doesn't work for me either (Answer in comments as this question is closed):

[image]

Comment: Usually just pressing enter after running a piece of code that does not print a newline will display a prompter. Or you can use the -l option.

Comment: @TLP Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: PRobably you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667/how-can-i-start-an-interactive-console-for-perl

Comment: It seems like you are opening a program, which expects end of file to end. You should show what you are doing to enter this mode.

Comment: Re "*I have asked a similar question elsewhere*", No, that was about a completely different program. /// Re "*it eventually evolved into a series of comments*", Debugging a problem requires info. If that info is not provided by the question, it must be requested.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't provide the name of a program, and you didn't provide a program via the `-e` or `-E` command line options, so it's reading the program from STDIN.

`perl` does have a builtin debugger that you access by passing `-d`, but you still need to provide a program. (You can provide a trivial one using `-e1`.)

See [How can I start an interactive console for Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73667/589924) for alternatives.